# AWS Autoscale termination policies

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I'm attempting to add an existing EC2 instance to an autoscale group I created as the initial instance. I've set the termination policy to 'NewestInstance' and if I understand correctly, when a new instance is spun up and added to the autoscale group, when my scale down trigger is hit, the last instance added to the group will be removed. What I've seen in testing though, is that the initial instance is always removed at some point. Am I misunderstanding the termination option, or am I missing some setting somewhere?

Comment: "I'm attempting to add an existing EC2 instance to an autoscale group I created as the initial instance." <-- that's not possible, and I'm not sure what it has to do with your question.

Comment: You can attach an existing instance to an autoscaling group  

    `as-attach-instances i-c3b4b8bc --auto-scaling-group FemSG --aws-credential-file ~/.awscreds.conf`

So if I attach a single instance to an autoscaling group and then set the termination policy to 'NewestInstance', shouldn't any subsequent instances that get spun up satisfy the termination condition?